# Tangent Sum of acute angles

Tags: geometry

I've found a lot of information of proving the tangent sum of acute angles using other trig identities.

However, how can one prove the following?
$$\tan(x+y)=\frac{\tan(x)+\tan(y)}{1-\tan(x)\tan(y)}$$

The definition of a tangent is $\tan(x)=\frac{N'-N}{1+NN'}$, where $N$ and $N'$ are the slopes of the lines that create the angle $x$.

How can we prove the identity using this definition?

Comment: $\sin(x+y)= \sin(x) \cos(y)+\cos(x) \sin(y)$ and $\cos(x+y)= \cos(x) \cos(y)-\sin(x) \sin(y)$ ... now use $ \tan \theta=\frac{ \sin(\theta)} {\cos(\theta)}$

Comment: I need to use the definition of tan given to prove it

Comment: Here is a geometric proof on the bottom of this link: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html

Comment: $ \tan (x+y)=\frac{ \sin(x+y)} {\cos(x+y)}= \cdots $ ... divide top & bottom by $\cos(x) \cos(y)$ ....